# GAE: python code to check if i'm on dev_appserver or deployed to appspot

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, dev-appserver

My GAE app uses OAUTH 2. Currently, I manually switch the `redirect_uri` between `http://localhost:8081/oauth2callback` and `myapp.appspot.com/oauth2callback` depending on whether do local testing with `dev_appserver` or if I deploy to appspot.com.

Is there some code (e.g. using `os.environ`) that I can use to automate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get you current domain name with `os.environ['SERVER_NAME']`.

You also can check this by version name:

```
import os
if os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'].startswith('dev'):
  pass  # it's localhost
else:
  pass  # it's uploaded on gae
```

Will be better to use `self.uri_for('callback-uri-name', _full=True)` for building callback uri if you use webapp2.

You have something like this in your routes.

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/oauth/callback', handler='oauth.CallbackHandler', name='callback-uri-name'),
])
```

Then, if you'll call `self.uri_for('callback-uri-name', _full=True)` you'll get something like `http://localhost:8080/oauth/callback` or `http://app-id.appspot.com/oauth/callback`.

For more information: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#building-uris

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Can you elaborate on the buiding the callback uri with `self.uri_for('callback-uri-name', _full=True)`? Or give a  link for more information? 
I use the gdata client (for Google Contacts API) and it simply takes the uri as an input parameter.

Comment: Thanks! One comment: I had to remove the quotes around the hander, i.e. `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/oauth/callback', handler=oauth.CallbackHandler, name='callback-uri-name'),
])`

Comment: and how can i check is using JAVA?