# Loading Files Locally Using GSUtil

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gsutil

Does anyone know a good way to load a set of files locally into the **Java** dev_appserver's emulated Cloud Storage.

This didn't work:

```
$ gsutil rsync gs://mybucket http://localhost:8888/mybucket
InvalidUrlError: Unrecognized scheme "http".
```

I'm open to suggestions on either:

1. How to load a bunch of files locally (preferably through gsutil)
2. How to point my local dev_appserver to a non-emulated bucket at Google

This is painful to test things out locally without proper data.  I'm trying to write some transformations to load data into BigQuery (from Datastore backups) and it won't be possible without some real data.

Comment: To copy data to a local dir with `rsync`, `gsutil rsync -d /localdirgs://mybucket/data`.

Comment: Local copy isn't an issue, what I need is a way to load this into my dev_appserver.

Comment: `dev_appserver`**.py** can be told what directories to use for local files, via command-line flags -- but, again, I don't know enough about Java to help.

Answer (score 1):

"How to point my local dev_appserver to a non-emulated bucket at Google": it's not documented all that clearly, but it **is** implemented in the `dev_appserver` and `cloudstorage`.

To verify what I'm saying, first `svn checkout http://appengine-gcs-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python gcs-client` to get cloudstorage's source code onto your machine (you'll need to install `subversion` if you don't have it already, but, that's free too:-).

Then, `cd gcs-client/src/cloudstorage/` and look at `storage_api.py`.  In the very first function `_get_storage_api`, the docstring says:

> ```
> On dev appserver, this instance by default will talk to a local stub
> unless common.ACCESS_TOKEN is set. That token will be used to talk
> to the real GCS.
> ```

So, look at `common.py`, and again in the first function, `set_access_token`, you'll see:

> Args:
>       access_token: you can get one by run 'gsutil -d ls' and copy the
>         str after 'Bearer'.

So there you are -- in every entry to your app (best in `appengine_config.py` in your root directory), import `cloudstorage`'s `common` module, then **if and only if you're on dev_appserver[*] call

```
common.set_access_token('whatever_the_token')
```

using as argument string the one you get by run 'gsutil -d ls', right after `Bearer` i.e among much else you'll spot something like (faking and way shortening the actual value...:-):

```
Bearer xy15.WKXJQEzXPQQy2dt7qK9\r\n
```

in which case you'd be calling

```
common.set_access_token('xy15.WKXJQEzXPQQy2dt7qK9')
```

[*] many ways to find out if you're on `dev_appserver`, e.g see [GAE: python code to check if i'm on dev_appserver or deployed to appspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741711/gae-python-code-to-check-if-im-on-dev-appserver-or-deployed-to-appspot) .

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Alex, really appreciate it.  I did find previous answers to this for Python, but not Java.  Sorry if that was confusing in my question, I tried to bold it to make it clear.  Do you know of the same for the Java SDK?

Comment: @BK-, sorry, my Java is weak -- somebody with strong Java should surely be able to find a similar approach in the Java SDK's sources, as I did in the Python SDK's sources!  If you **only** want Java answers, add Java to your tags -- this way, those of us who know too little Java to help will know not to try to help you...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex. Added the tag! :-)

Comment: @BK- When you say you found answers for python, was this for your second question, or your first as well? I also want to preload some GCS data on my dev appserver, but can't find a way.

Comment: Neither was answered. Sorry! :(